# Circle Collision class not positioning itself correctly

Tags: unity, physics

Ok I am using unity3D and the Futile framework. I have everything drawing and working correctly with Futile, but I am trying to attach a circle collision class to the FSprite that I have. I must be missing something but I have tried everything I can think of.

Right now, it positions itself offset from the center of the texture. The picture below shows what I am talking about. (The blue circle filled circle is my round Planet and the red circle is the circle class)
[image: Offset Circle Class]

Below is my Planet class constructor

```
public Planet(string texture, Vector2 position, Team team, Level level = Level.One)
    : base(texture)
{
    Debug.Log("Texture Rect width: " + this.textureRect.width.ToString());

    //this.anchorX = .5f;
    //this.anchorY = .5f;
    this.Position = position;
    collision = new Circle(this.textureRect.width / 2, this.Position);
    collision.Position = this.Position;



    FAtlasManager am = Futile.atlasManager;
    levelOneTexture = am.GetElementWithName("Circle.png");
    levelOneTexture = am.GetElementWithName("Planet_1.png");
    levelTwoTexture = am.GetElementWithName("Planet_2.png");
    levelThreeTexture = am.GetElementWithName("Planet_3.png");
    ChangePlanetTeam(team);
    ChangePlanetLevel(level);
    SetPlanetLevelTexture(level);

    float rot = RXRandom.Range(0, 2 * Mathf.PI);
    this.rotation = rot;
}
```

And here is my Circle class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;



public class Circle
{
    private float radius = 1f;
    private Vector2 position = Vector2.zero;
    private Vector2 origin = Vector2.zero;

    public float Radius
    {
        get { return radius; }
        set { radius = value; }
    }
    public Vector2 Position
    {
        get { return position; }
        set 
        {
            float x = value.x + Radius;
            float y = value.y + Radius;
            position = new Vector2(x, y);
            //position = value;
        }
    }
    public float X { get { return Position.x; } }
    public float Y { get { return Position.y; } }


    public Circle(float radius, Vector2 position)
    {
        Debug.Log("Circle position: " + position.ToString());
        this.Position = position;
        this.radius = radius;
        Debug.Log("Radius: " + radius.ToString());
    }

    public void DrawRadius()
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(this.X, this.Y, 0), new Vector3(this.X + Radius, this.Y + radius,0));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Test if two circles are currently colliding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">One of the circles to test</param>
    /// <param name="b">The other circle to test</param>
    /// <returns>True if collision is present</returns>
    public static bool CircleToCircleCollision(Circle a, Circle b)
    {
        return ((a.Radius + b.Radius) > Vector2.Distance(a.Position, b.Position));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Test if a certain circle contains a point
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">The circle to test</param>
    /// <param name="point">The point to test</param>
    /// <returns>Returns true if circle contains the point</returns>
    public static bool CircleContainsPoint(Circle a, Vector2 point)
    {
        return a.Radius > Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(a.X, a.Y), point);
    }

    public bool CircleContainsPoint(Vector2 point)
    {
        return Circle.CircleContainsPoint(this, point);
    }
}
```

I guess my collision code could be wrong but I dont believe so. I am passing in a point to determine if the click was inside of the circle.

Perhaps my math is wrong, or i dont understand the Futile coordinate system like I should, but I am at a loss.

I have checked to ensure that the texture I use for the planet is square(128x128), and that the actual circle is perfectly centered.

I can get the circle close but not perfect. There is always a registered click where it shouldnt be.

Also I tried to tag this post with "Futile" but it would not let me due to reputation.

Comment: Also, That image I added is just an example, I can get the circle to move around the planet and can get it close but it never lines up the way it should.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I dont really program in c#. However, I've had this problem once before and realised that I had added the radius of the circle to the x and y position which offsets the collision circle from the circle sprite.

```
 public void DrawRadius()
{
    Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(this.X, this.Y, 0), new Vector3(this.X + Radius, this.Y + radius,0));
}
```

In your DrawRadius() method you "this.X + Radius"...

If I am not mistaken, this should be "this.X - Radius"

Like this:

```
 public void DrawRadius()
{
    Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(this.X, this.Y, 0), new Vector3(this.X - Radius, this.Y - radius,0));
}
```

Make sure you apply the "- Radius".

Be aware, I have little to no experience in C#. However, I'm just trying to help :)

Give that a go.

Comment: I will give this a try when i get home as well, I have tried a bunch of combinations of subtracting and adding to the x,y. but maybe i messed it up once.

Comment: Is C# the same as java in regards to x and y co-ordinate origins?
Java's x and y co-oridinates start at the top left corner... If this is the case then "+ Radius" has no purpose at all... and to centre the x and y co-oridnates in the middle of the circle you must "- Radius"

Comment: Btw- You do realise you have 2 different "Radius" and "radius" and you call them BOTH in the drawRadius() method? Is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: No, its not supposed to be like that was a typo. but they both return the same value none the less. Radius is a property that returns radius

Comment: Unity is a bit different with its coordinate system, and futile is supposed to change it over to a flash/cocos system(which i dont really know to be honest.) I will try the -Radius again when I get home in about 2 hours. and see if i forgot to check that one before.

Comment: Ok no worries, If that doesn't work then I can write up a program in java using a circle sprite and rendering its collision circle if that would help? Since java is very similar to C# it may help you with the math :)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you are deliberately offsetting the collision circle’s centre:

```
       float x = value.x + Radius;
       float y = value.y + Radius;
```

Comment: I have tried it without the offset, however that places my circle at the top-left of the sprite. However, I will give it a try once I get home in about 2 hours.